# Laravel / PHP / MySQL - Packets out of order

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, oracle, mysql-cluster

Application coded in Laravel (5.2) / PHP (5.6) using PDO library is generating **Packets out of order** exception on random requests (Specially after we setup cluster environment with Oracle / MySql 8.0). Below is the complete exception

local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 0. Packet size=145' in /code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:335
Next exception 'Illuminate\Database\QueryException' with message 'Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 0. Packet size=145

We have already tried following parameters in php application code while creating connection.

- $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

And setup following parameters at mysql server configuration end

- max_allowed_packets

Comment: Your PHP version has been unsupported and as a result insecure for three years now.

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz. Right now we are focusing on the fix of this exception, if the PHP version is unsupported then we should have this error on each request but the behavior is random.

Comment: I'm not saying it's causing this specific issue (I'd have made it an answer in that case), I'm saying it's something dangerous that you should fix ASAP.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, can you please help regarding the fix of that exception.

Comment: What have you set `max_allowed_packets` to?

Comment: It is set to 1G (1 GB)

Comment: Anyone with a solution to above issue ?